# how to execute different print function based on the users input

Tags: python, if-statement, input

I am a complete beginner to coding and python so It is probably very simple. So my problem is that am learning how to put if and else function based on the users input and i dont know how to connect between the two.

```
age = input("enter your age: ")
yes = "welcome"
no = "too bad then"
ans = [yes, no]
if age == "18":
    print(yes)
else: 
    input("you're not old enough, would you like to enter anyways?: {ans} ")
    if yes:
        print(yes)
    else:
        print(no)
```

this is the code i made based on what ive learned so far it is probably full of mistake. I wanted to connect the 'if' and 'else' function to the `input("you're not old enough, would you like to enter anyways?: {ans} ")`
the answer would be yes or no which would print diffrent things.

Comment: _print(yes if ((age := input("enter your age: ")) == 18) else yes if input(f"you're not old enough, would you like to enter anyways?: {ans} ") == yes else no)_.

Comment: @Bama I have made quite a few updates to the original answer so check back and let me know if you have any questions

Comment: `print` is the same function in both cases; you want to call it with different arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function. I named it `message` here, which prints `welcome`
if `True` is passed and prints `too bad then` if `False` is passed:

```py
# Use int while you ask for an integer
age = int(input("enter your age: "))

def message(msg):
    if msg is True:
        print("welcome")
    elif msg is False:
        print("too bad then")

if age == 18: #It's probably "age >= 18" that you need
    message(True)
else: 
    enter = input("you're not old enough, would you like to enter anyways?: ")
    if enter.strip().lower() in ["yes","y"]:
        message(True)
    elif enter.strip().lower() in ["n","no"]:
        message(False)
    else:
        print("Invalid input exiting...")
```

Comment: 1) you don't need to check `if boolean is True`, you can simply do: `if boolean` 2)what happens when the age is greater than 18? are 90-year-olds too young? 3) if the answer isn't explicitly yes, you should assume it's no to avoid more edge cases, for example, what of the entered message is `unsure` or 'maybe'? you don't need to be that explicit and `print("Invalid input exiting...")`

Answer (score 0):

Note that when using `or`, as soon as the first expression (in the order specified) is `True`, the next expressions are ignored since the result will be `True` regardless. The same happens when using `and`; as soon as a `False` is found, the next expressions are ignored since the result will be `False`

For your specific question the solution is:

```
if int(input("enter your age: ")) >= 18 or input("you're not old enough, would you like to enter anyways? ").lower().startswith('y'):
    print("welcome")  
else: 
    print("too bad then")
```

for a more general-purpose task (writing an interpreter or similar) you need to use function pointers and a look-up table (usually a dictionary).
Here is a working example:

```
import math
import time

def add(*args):
    "Adds numbers together"
    if len(args)>0:
        print(sum((float(arg) for arg in args)))

def mult(*args):
    "Multiplies numbers together"
    if len(args)>0:
        print(math.prod((float(arg) for arg in args)))
        
def nothing(*args):
    pass
        
def alias(*args):
    "Creates a new alias for a given action"
    action, alias, *_ = args
    if action not in LUT:
        print("Cannot create an alias for an undefined action!")
    else:
        aliases[alias]=action
        print(f"Successfully created alias '{alias}' for '{action}'")
    
def print_help(*args):
    "Displays valid options and what they do"
    for keyword in LUT:
        doc = LUT[keyword].__doc__
        print(f"{keyword} : {doc if doc is not None else '?'}")
    print(f"To exit the program, type any one of: {', '.join(termination_keywords)}")
    
def print_aliases(*args):
    groupings= {action : [] for action in LUT}
    for alias in aliases:
        groupings[aliases[alias]].append(alias)
    for action, aliases_ in groupings.items():
        if len(aliases_)>0:
            print(f"{action} : {', '.join(aliases_)}")
    
# Look Up Table
LUT = {
    'help':print_help,
    'add':add,
    'mult':mult,
    'nop' : nothing,
    'alias' : alias,
    'print_aliases': print_aliases
    }

aliases = {
    '+':'add',
    'sum':'add',
    'total': 'add',
    '*':'mult',
    'multiply':'mult',
    'prod':'mult',
    'nothing' : 'nop',
    'pass': 'nop'
}
    
termination_keywords = {'end','exit','quit','q'}

print(f"""Enter your the desired action and its arguments as space seperated values.
For example: add 1 2 3 4 5

Defined actions are:""")
print_help()
# Sometimes the input is displayed before the help is done printing, a small delay fixes the issue
time.sleep(0.5)

while True:
    print("#"*20)
    action, *args = input("What do you want to do? ").split(' ')
    action = action.lower()
    if action in termination_keywords:
        break;
    if action in LUT:
        LUT[action](*args)
    elif action in aliases:
        LUT[aliases[action]](*args)
    else:
        print("Undefined action!")
```

Comment: The direct answer is ok, but you are being downvoted for being too detailed in the next part. Please consider that the question was asked by a beginner.

Comment: Exactly, it's best to learn best practices and correct approaches to a problem rather than just using the excuse of being a beginner to learn poor programming. The amount of comically bad code I have to fix on a daily basis stems from "beginner" programmers who didn't bother to learn how to do something. you may also want to check the daily wtf https://thedailywtf.com/