# How can I optimize my code to deal with 100+ inputs?

Tags: python

I'm trying to solve a problem that gives me a couple inputs that determine some calculations I have to do to get the correct outputs. To achieve this I have come up with two different coding solutions using python that are both capable of solving the problem but only on a relatively small scale but I need it to work for larger numbers of inputs.
The inputs are given in the form of:
A number representing the number of calculations.
A calculation consisting of method, first number, second number.
Repeat the above however many times.

The numbers in the calculations can also be references to other calculations in the form of '$' + 'index of referenced calculation'

Here's the somewhat nicer code I've come up with:

```
table = []
results = []

def eval(list_num ,list):
    if '$' not in list[1] and '$' not in list[2]:
        calc(list_num, list)
    else:
        if '$' in list[1]:
            if results[int(list[1][1])] != ' ':
                list[1] = results[int(list[1][1])]
        if '$' in list[2]:
            if results[int(list[2][1])] != ' ':
                list[2] = results[int(list[2][1])]

def calc(cell, variab):
    if variab[0] == 'VALUE':
        results[cell] = variab[1]
    elif variab[0] == 'ADD':
        results[cell] = str(int(variab[1]) + int(variab[2]))
    elif variab[0] == 'SUB':
        results[cell] = str(int(variab[1]) - int(variab[2]))
    elif variab[0] == 'MULT':
        results[cell] = str(int(variab[1]) * int(variab[2]))


n = int(input())
for i in range(n):
    operation, arg_1, arg_2 = input().split()
    table.append([operation, arg_1, arg_2])
    results.append(' ')
while ' ' in results:
    for i in range(n):
        eval(i, table[i])

for i in range(n):
    print(results[i])
```

Comment: FYI, should not use `list` as a variable name.  It shadows the `list` type and makes the code look confusing.  `eval` is also a built-in function.

Comment: I'm honestly not even sure what your question is. Where do you see the need to optimize anything? Apart from that, I've noticed quite some unusual things, so consider submitting this to codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand your "VALUE" command but the rest can be written as:

```
results = []

ops = {
    'add' : lambda a,b: a+b,
    'sub' : lambda a,b: a-b,
    'mult' : lambda a,b: a*b,
}

def parse(arg):
    if arg.isnumeric():
        return float(arg)
    elif arg.startswith('$'):
        return results[int(arg[1:])]
    else:
        raise Exception(f"Invalid argument: {arg}")

def process(*args):
    if len(args)!=3:
        raise Exception(f"Expected 3 inputs but got {len(args)}")
    op, a, b = args
    op = op.lower()
    if op not in ops:
        raise Exception(f"Undefined operation: {op}")
    else:
        a = parse(a)
        b = parse(b)
        results.append(ops[op](a,b))


for i in range(int(input('How many calculations do you want to perform? '))):
    process(*(input('Expression: ').strip().split(' ')))

for result in results:
    print(result)
```

Example of a run:

```
How many calculations do you want to perform? 3
Expression: add 2 3
Expression: mult $0 20
Expression: sub $-1 5
5.0
100.0
95.0
```

edit: you may find the more detailed answer here useful:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/77467902/7121783

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @MarkTolonen I didn't? it's the output of the execution, not a piece of code,data or error

Comment: It's text. text should be pasted as text when possible.  Read the link for reasons.